# Concept of file manager in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I am unknown of file manager in iphone

Can anyone explain the concept of file manager here

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the Apple [Low-Level File Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/Classes.html)

> You use an NSFileManager object to
>   perform many generic file-system
>   operations—for example you can:
>
> > Create directories and files.
> >
> > Extract
> >     the contents of files (as NSData
> >     objects)
> >
> > Change your current working location in the file system.
> >
> > Copy, move, and link files and directories.
> >
> > Remove files, links, and directories.
> >
> > ...

An important point to understand is that your application runs in a "sandbox" - it has access only to its own files, not files created by other applications.

The section on [the file system](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html) in the iOS Application Programming Guide describes the layout of your application and any files it creates.

For example, here's how you might use NSFileManager to open a file named "Defaults.plist" in your application bundle and read it into an NSData object:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Defaults" ofType:@"plist"];

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
```